# Ошибка при инициализации нейронной сети в OpenVINO: Unsupported primitive of type

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети, openvino

OpenVINO при загрузке сети выдаёт ошибку.

Код:

```
    // 1 - Читаем сеть
    InferenceEngine::Core core;
    InferenceEngine::CNNNetReader network_reader;
    network_reader.ReadNetwork(modelXmlName);
    network_reader.ReadWeights(modelBinName);

    // 2 - Получаем сеть из класса-читалки
    auto network = network_reader.getNetwork();

    // 3 - Получаем информацию о входах и выходах сети
    InferenceEngine::InputsDataMap input_info(network.getInputsInfo());
    InferenceEngine::OutputsDataMap output_info(network.getOutputsInfo());

    // 4 - Конфигурируем входы и выходы сети
    for (auto &item : input_info)
    {
        auto input_data = item.second;
        input_data->setPrecision(InferenceEngine::Precision::U8);
        input_data->setLayout(InferenceEngine::Layout::NCHW);
        input_data->getPreProcess().setResizeAlgorithm(InferenceEngine::RESIZE_BILINEAR);
        input_data->getPreProcess().setColorFormat(InferenceEngine::ColorFormat::RGB);
    }

    // 5 - Загружаем сеть
    auto executable_network = core.LoadNetwork(network, "CPU");
```

Вызов

```
auto executable_network = core.LoadNetwork(network, "CPU");
```

выкидывает исключение, содержание которого следующее:

```
Unsupported primitive of type: DetectionOutput name: DetectionOutput_
```

Что сделано неправильно? Такое впечатление, что надо было до этого вызова ещё что-то настроить, но я не могу понять, что именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае не хватает одной инструкции:

```
core.AddExtension(std::make_shared<InferenceEngine::Extensions::Cpu::CpuExtensions>(), "CPU");
```

После добавления программа успешно отрабатывает до конца.